# Potential Future Exposure for vanilla swap

Tags: option-pricing, interest-rates, risk, monte-carlo, modeling

I need to calculate the PFE for vanilla swap. I wonder if it makes sense to simulate the MC scenarios with a 1-factor Hull white model. In my opinion, this model only allows parallel curve deformations and future MTMs would not be representative of reality!
I would like to know what market practice is?

Comment: One common market practice, that you may want to consider using, is to simulate curve movemenconsider using, its historical principal components. The first PC is also close to parallel shift, but the others change the curve shape is other ways.

Comment: If you have only one swap to evaluate , you obviously don’t need a multi factor model.  If you have a portfolio , you do.